# Question regarding Time dilation of satellites

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, satellites

My name is Shaun Kant.

I was wondering about why the satellite's time is **faster** with respect to Earth's time. [PBS space time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKxQTvqcpSg) mentions that fact. However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#/media/File:Soyuz_TMA-1_at_the_ISS.jpg) mentions that at the ISS (International Space Station), time ticks slower for the satellite with respect to Earth's time. According to this formula,

\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta t'}{\Delta t} = \frac{2W/\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}}{2W/c} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} = \gamma
\end{align}

it mentions that two observers will experience different times if one is in motion, by a factor of gamma. If we now say that *$\Delta t$* is the person on the ISS and *$\Delta t'$* is the observer on Earth, we can conclude that relative to the person experiencing Earth time, that person on the ISS is experiencing slower time than the person on Earth.

However, sources such as PBS Space Time and another [Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278165/) mention that because the ISS is not as close to Earth, it experiences a faster time than Earth.

How is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different and opposing phenomena at work here.

One is gravitational time dilation. This causes clocks at higher altitudes to tick faster than clocks at lower altitudes.

The other is kinematic time dilation. This causes clocks at higher speeds to tick slower than clocks at lower speeds.

Clocks in satellites at low orbits are slowed by their speed more than they are sped up by their altitude. So the ISS clocks lose about $25\mathrm{\ \mu s/day}$. While high orbits are sped up more by their altitude than they are slowed by their speed. So GPS clocks gain about $40\mathrm{\ \mu s/day}$

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

Comment: The last paragraph seems to contradict with the initial information you gave me; maybe a typo? Do you have any other references I could use, because I cannot digest the Wikipedia information? Thank you!

Comment: @ShaunKant I have rephrased the last paragraph. Regarding “why orbits at lower altitudes are faster than orbits at higher altitudes”. That is just standard Newtonian gravity.

Comment: Thank you Dale!

Comment: Edit: I deleted the comments after reading that you meant that orbits go faster, not time